Are there any programs that show the highest limits order on the market?
Super noob here, and I'm sure this is already a thing but I can't find it...
Often times on various stocks there are huge limit orders that have a have a high likelihood of bouncing the price. I was curious if there is any program or app that tracks, for example, the highest limit order compared to the market cap, or something similar. It would have to show ratio of limit order to market cap, otherwise all of the largest limit orders on the books would just be the largest market cap stocks on the market
